# Prove $a^4+b^4 \geq a^3b$

Tags: inequality

How would you prove that $a^4+b^4 \geq a^3b$ for every real $a$ and $b$?
I solved it using the convexity of the $x^4$ function, but I am wandering for a more direct solution. Thanks

Comment: Yes, we can make it,  of course. Show please  your attempts and I'll do it.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I solved it using the convexity of the $x^4$ function, but I was wandering for a more direct approach, such as the one given by Alan below.

Answer (score 3):

Below is the proof in the case $a,b\ge 0$. The other cases are either the same (when $a,b\le 0$) or obvious (if $ab\le 0$).

If $a\ge b$ then $a^3b\le a^4\le a^4+b^4$. If $a<b$ then $ a^3b< b^4\le a^4+b^4$. Q.E.D.

Comment: Note that these inequalites manipulations are true only for positive numbers. Of course $a^4+b^4\ge a^3b$ is trivially true when $a^3b<0$ and the case $a,b<0$ is the same as $a,b>0$, but it needs to be stated.

Comment: I added a few words about other cases.

Answer (score 2):

For $ab<0$, the claim is trivial, since the left-hand side is positive and the right-hand side is negative. For $ab\geqslant 0$, a stronger inequality holds:
$$a^4+b^4\geqslant a^3b+ab^3 \iff (a-b)^2(a^2+ab+b^2)\geqslant0$$
which can easily be shown to be true. The claim follows.